# Android parse json from multiple url

Tags: android, json

I can parse json from an url in this way:

```
String link1 = "http://www.url.com/test1.json";
String link2 = "http://www.url.com/test2.json";
private void fetchMovies() {
    String url = link1;
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject movieObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                int rank = movieObj.getInt("rank");
                                String title = movieObj.getString("title");
                                Movie m = new Movie(rank, title);
                                movieList.add(0, m);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

I want to parse my json from multiple url.

I want to parse url1 and url2 at the same time.

How can I do that?

Comment: There is an **object** inside a `JSON` object, **not**  an array.

Comment: @Dennis I have updated my post. Can you check it?

Comment: Hi, you can't parse two `JSON` objects at the same time, but you can parse them consecutively(one after another).  Well, I can't think of any hypothetical(imaginary) situation where you'll need to parse two `JSON` objects and save them into one class. If you'll work in an industry, you'll realize that the employee from the server end will prepare the `JSON` accordingly so you don't need to parse two `JSON` at the same time.

Comment: @Dennis I use this tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/

I have more than 10 links and  all json have the same structure.

Comment: oh hahaha, dude, they are two separate JSON`s  You need to parse them separately. One has a `JSON ARRAY` and other usually has `JSON OBJECT`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use "links" as array  ?
In case you will use an array:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray keys = jsonObject.getJSONArray("links");
int length = keys.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    new ReadJSON().execute(keys.getString(i));
}
```

Anyway, you take all the keys and go one after the other, and then query each
EDIT:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(/*Your links json*/);
JSONObject links = jsonObject.get("links");
Iterator<String> keys = links.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    new ReadJSON().execute(links.getString(keys.next()));
}
```

Comment: There is an **object** inside a `JSON` object, **not**  an array. Shouldn't it be `"links:[ .... ]` ?

Comment: @Dennis I agree that it is better to use links, I asked that first in my comment.

I assumed that he has a good reason for that :) In case he will change it to links, he can use my code just go over the JSONArray values

Comment: Hi @Dennis Thanks for your help. I got this issue "cannot resolve method 'execute(java.lang.object)' " when I try your code.

Comment: You changed the asynctask name to ReadJSON2

Comment: Ahh sorry @fbwnd , I tried your code and I got issue. I have updated my post, please check it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Use toString() on the get result

Comment: Thanks for all @fbwnd I tried your last post but not work. Thank you.

Comment: @fbwnd  I have updated my question. Can you check it?

Comment: @Johny I don't really understand what is your issue, and I don't think you should edit your question to completely different question. if you have another issue you should create a new thread.

As for your questions, call each one of the request with diff url on a diff thread, it will not ensure that you can do is on the same time, but it will be as close as possible